# Отправка данных в БД из поля GUI

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы после отправки данных, форма была снова пустой для следующей партии данных на отправку в БД.

Я создал форму для текста и кнопку. Но после отправки последнее значение отправляется постоянно. (Но мне нужно сделать что бы после отправки одного значения, снова просил ввода.)

```py
import pymysql.cursors
import pymysqlpool
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
 

connection = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                             user='root',
                             password='',
                             db='python',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
                             autocommit=True)


def display_full_name():
    # Подключение к БД
    counter = True
    x=1
    while counter:
        text = name.get()
        x=x+1
    
        try:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                # Отправка SQL запроса
                sql = "INSERT INTO `scaner` (`number`) VALUES (%s)"
                cursor.execute(sql, (text))

            # Сохранение изменения 
            connection.commit()

        finally:
                print('Отправленно!')

        if x>1000000:
            counter=False
            connection.close()

 
root = Tk()
root.title("Считыватель Штрих кодов и комит в БД")
 
name = StringVar()

name_label = Label(text="Введите штрихкод:")

name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")

name_entry = Entry(textvariable=name)

name_entry.grid(row=0,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

message_button = Button(text="Отправить", command=display_full_name)
message_button.grid(row=2,column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")
 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: А зачем вы миллион раз дублируете одну запись?

Comment: Пытаюсь сделать что бы код работал, но пока это плохо получается.

Comment: Вы можете подсказать как сделать что бы цикл работал и после отправки он снова просил данные для ввода.

Answer (score 0):

Привожу пример на `sqlite`, но на логику это никак не влияет. Все просто: нажатие на кнопку вызывает обработчик, который производит запись в базу, очищает поле ввода. Все, программа готова к записи следующего значения.

```py
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *


def display_full_name(conn, val, entry):
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("insert into codes (val) values (?)", (val,))
    conn.commit()
    entry.delete(0, 'end')


with sqlite3.connect("/tmp/tmp.db") as conn:

    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("create table codes (val int)")
    conn.commit()

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Считыватель Штрих кодов и комит в БД")
    name = StringVar()
    name_label = Label(text="Введите штрихкод:")
    name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
    name_entry = Entry(textvariable=name)
    name_entry.grid(row=0,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    message_button = Button(text="Отправить", command=lambda: display_full_name(conn, name.get(), name_entry))
    message_button.grid(row=2,column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: У вас данные для базы данных берутся из другого файла верно? я возился и как то у меня удалось сделать, что бы данные отправлялись в базу данных и очищалась форма. но заметил спустя N количество времени соединение разрывается, подскажите есть методы что бы постоянно поддерживалось активное подключение?

Comment: Нет, в моем примере открывается пустая база, создается таблица, туда вносятся записи по нажатию кнопки.

Comment: Сейчас я вожусь как сделать постоянное активное подключение. и создать две Radiobutton что бы пользователь сам выбирал в какую ячейку ему записывать данные. в сети нашел примерно похожий код не удаеться его переделать под свою прогграму ъ

Comment: Если вы поняли принцип создания такого приложения, то чужой код вам не нужен, пишите свой. А если возникают какие-то трудности, создавайте новые вопросы по конкретной проблеме.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/943539/%D0%90%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D0%91%D0%94