# Активное подключение к БД

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных

Подскажите как постоянно отправлять данные в бд.
Я написал мини-прогу которая отправляет данные в бд, но заметил один момент если подождать N время соединение разрываеться, я когда писал подобное приложение в терминале, я там использовал цикл и соединение было всегда активное, а сейчас интерфейс делаю и не знаю как это реализовать.

Мой код:

```
import pymysql.cursors
import pymysqlpool
from tkinter import *
 
# Подключение к БД
connection = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                             user='root',
                             password='',
                             db='python',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
                             autocommit=True)

 
root = Tk()
root.title("Считыватель Штрих кодов и комит в БД")



def func(event):
    label = Label(text = name.get())
    
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            # Отправка SQL запроса
            sql = "INSERT INTO `scaner` (`number`) VALUES (%s)"
            cursor.execute(sql, (label['text']))

        # Сохранение изменения
        connection.commit()
        

    finally:
        print(label['text'])
        name_entry.delete(0, END)
root.bind('<Return>', func) 
def display_full_name():
    
    label = Label(text = name.get())
    
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            # Отправка SQL запроса
            sql = "INSERT INTO `scaner` (`number`) VALUES (%s)"
            cursor.execute(sql, (label['text']))

        # Сохранение изменения
        connection.commit()

    finally:
        print(label['text'])
        name_entry.delete(0, END)



name = StringVar()
name_label = Label(text="Введите штрихкод:")
name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
name_entry = Entry(textvariable=name)
name_entry.grid(row=0,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
message_button = Button(text="Отправить", command=display_full_name)
message_button.grid(row=2,column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я бы сделал на вашем месте что-то вроде класса-коннектора к БД, у которого, например будет метод `execute`, в котором перед исполнением будете проверять активно ли соединение с бд, если нет, то делать реконнект.
Что-то вроде такого:

```py
class DBExecutor():
    def __init__(self, **connection_params):
        self._connection_params = connection_params
        self._connection = None

    def _connect(self):
        self._connection = pymysql.connect(**self._connection_params)

    def execute(self, sql, *args, **kwargs):
        if not (self._connection and self._connection.ping(True)):
            self._connect():
        with self._connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(sql, *args, **kwargs)

        self._connection.commit()

# использование
db_executor = DBExecutor(host='127.0.0.1', user='root', password='', db='python', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor, autocommit=True)
db_executor.execute("INSERT INTO `scaner` (`number`) VALUES (%s)", ('text',))
```

Comment: Спасибо что ответили, я пытался вставить ваш код, но выходит ошибка на 15 сточке и понять не могу почему.

Comment: http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/Snimok.1550129160.png

Comment: @АндрДжаканов, Вы серьёзно? у Вас пробел лишний перед строчкой, а ещё, это псевдо-код, показывающий общую идею решения, не факт что он вообще будет работать

Comment: Спасибо все работает, да в пробеле была ошибка и лишняя : я только осваиваю python, набираюсь опыта.